# Toshiba Laptop Black Screen Of Death

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot, bsod

A friend of mine has asked me to repair his laptop as it is experiencing the BSOD. I've tried entering cmd with ctrl+alt+del but to no avail. I've also tried the sticky keys method, this also didn't work. I've tried about every option on the f8 repair menu.

I've also tried reinstalling windows on his computer with a USb that does in fact work on other systems. The windows installation stalls on the setup is starting.

At that point, I'm able to get a window open using shift+f10 but when I try using diskpart, nothing happens and it displays a message saying MINWINPC. I've also seen a few people online claiming you can use bootrec.exe but when I run >bootrec.exe/FixBoot I'm told no drivers are loaded, then 0 windows installations are found.

I've tried booting a bootable linux usb but it stalls on a black screen also.

Is this a sign of a broken hard drive? Can someone try offering me some advice.

Answer (score 0):

Loading a Linux image from a live USB disk does use the computer's hard drive at all. You can run Linux via USB so long as your computer can boot from CD/DVD/USB and has enough RAM. If the live boot fails, make sure that USB is your first boot option in BIOS. **USB needs to be set as the first boot device in the menu** if you want it to take priority over Windows. Unless you wrote a bad image to the USB and it fails to decompress the kernel, Linux should then boot without a problem.

For Toshiba laptops, I recommend trying out the Toshiba recovery environment, if the recovery partition is still on the computer. It's an extremely simple tool and will do a factory reset of the computer. Alternatively, it can also reset the computer but save the C:\Users folder. Make sure that **everything important** on the hard drive is backed up before attempting any of this.

You may want to try using an open source program like [uNetbootin](https://github.com/unetbootin/unetbootin) to get a Linux image (say, Ubuntu) written to the USB disk. This will let you access the NTFS file system, back up the data, and run a file system check on Windows with ***NTFSprogs*** and ***fsck***.

**EDIT**: Additionally, if you're able to, please post the Windows error codes/messages that come up during the BSOD, as the community may be able to diagnose this issue without you having to do a reset of the laptop.

**EDIT 2:** Since I can't post this as a comment @ the OP, have you tried using a Windows disk? This will take the responsibility away from Windows on the HDD (whatever state it's in) and allow you to use the recovery tools built into the disk. You can access this by using the Advanced repair mode on the disk, which allows the use of command prompt. You may want to try [these commands](http://www.sevenforums.com/general-discussion/17521-how-fix-mbr-through-command-prompt.html) instead of the one you used, though I am not sure it's the MBR.

```
    bootrec /scanos
    bootrec /rebuildbcd
    bootrec /fixmbr
```

Comment: The linux usb I made is fine, it runs on my desktop without a hitch and it has boot priority over the hard drive. The toshiba recovery environment won't launch, It stalls right after selecting it. Edit: There is no error codes displayed.

Comment: None of the above have worked thus far. Right now I've managed to boot into a 32bit version of Ubuntu and can extract his data but is there anything I can try while I'm here?

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Yes, once you've backed up the data, I recommend following this tutorial. I've had to do similar operations to both OS X and Windows. https://linuxacademy.com/blog/linux/ntfs-partition-repair-and-recovery-in-linux/